# In a web service application, is verb-orientation still useful?

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, soa

Thanks for looking!

### Background

I am building a strictly machine-to-machine web-service (restful) application.  The application will listen for requests, retrieve data, construct objects, serialize to JSON and return the JSON object.

This application will ultimately be used by other web applications as well as iOS apps, Android apps, and even desktop apps.

The existing code that I have inherited makes a distinction based on *how* the service was called in terms of HTTP verbs (GET, POST, etc).

### Question

In this day and age of machine-to-machine communication, is the HTTP verb even relevant any longer?  Could it in fact be constraining for future adoption of the service API to base the code around HTTP verbs?

### Update

`fmgp` provides a clear answer to "why" these verbs are used, but I feel should I clarify my concern:

Will other platforms such as iOS or Android (for example) be able to originate HTTP verb-based calls like `GET` and `POST`?  If the answer is "no" then I assume that we should stay away from relying on these verbs and instead build the desired action into the request URL as a parameter.

Comment: Can you add an example? I'm not sure, do you mean urls like `/getUser/123` and `/putUser`? It just doesn't sound very restful and I never heard of this being a practice.

Comment: Sure, if I `GET` "users/someUserId", the code recognizes that the request is get-based and returns a user object containing info about that user.  If I `POST` "users/someUserId" and send with the post a user object with, say, an altered first name drawn from a form, then the code updates the database with the new first name.

Comment: Ok, I got the question wrong. I somehow though you meant the naming of the services, i.e. literally using get/post as part of the url. Using http methods is a core concept of restful services. You even need to use this sometimes, for example you should not use `GET` to update your database, as multiple identical request may be cached by an intermediate server.

Comment: Thanks kapep, that makes good sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RestFul applications, you have a verb foreach CRUD operation:

- Create: POST
- Read: GET
- Update: PUT
- Delete: DELETE

Everything claimed "restful" will work the same way according to this philosophy.

There's nothing standard in that, just a clean, good designed, easy to understand programming style. Of course you may want to do all operation with only GET and some query parameters as soon as your client and server can handle it.

Comment: That, helps fmgp, thanks.  I would like to see what others think as well be for closing the question.  Thanks again.

Comment: Actually that's not true. HTTP verb do not map exactly to CRUD.GET and DELETE are right but POST is create when the target URI is determined by server (and sometimes partial update) and PUT is replace resource or create resource when the client sets the URI